# Can't understand: ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "

Tags: bash, shell, unix, math

Here is my script:

```
elif [[ $1 = "diff" ]]
then
        if [[ $2 ]] && [[ $3 ]]
        then
                city1=$2
                city2=$3
                file="worldcities.csv"
                pop1=$(awk -F, -v city="$city1" '$1 == city {print $8}' "$file")
                pop2=$(awk -F, -v city="$city2" '$1 == city {print $8}' "$file")

                echo "pop of $city1, $pop1"
                echo "pop of $city2, $pop2"

                diff=$((pop1 - pop2))
                echo "$diff"
        else
                exit 4
        fi
```

Here is my intended output:

```
pop of New York, 18972871
pop of Montreal, 3519595
15453276
```

Instead, I get the following and I am having trouble understanding the syntax error:

```
pop of New York, 18972871
pop of Montreal, 3519595
")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
```

Comment: Means you have a stray carriage return (a character that, when printed, sends the cursor to the left side of the terminal). Make sure you're reading a UNIX text file, not a DOS/Windows text file, as input. (The particular code style you're using means you'd have a bunch of syntax errors -- from `$'then\r'` being used instead of `then`, `$'fi\r'` instead of `fi`, etc -- if your script itself were saved with DOS newlines; so it's definitely the data files used as input, not the script itself, in the case at hand).

Comment: Another question about the same problem: [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](/q/45772525/4518341)

Comment: Regarding `diff=$((pop1 - pop2))` - [`diff`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/diff.html) is the name of a command, don't use variables that have the same names as commands as that'll obfuscate your code at best.

Comment: Since the only arithmetic context in your script is the calculation of `diff`, I would do two things: First have a look at the content of the variables. `echo` is a poor choice here. I would do a i.e. `xxd <<<$pop1`.  After this, turn on tracing with `set -x` and see what you get. This should show you the error.

Comment: BTW, a slightly simpler way to write your calculation would be `((diff=pop1-pop2))`.